# Bubbling chilli sauce

Tags: chili

I've made a chili sauce mainly with fresh chili, herbs and spices and olive oil & small bit of balsamic vinegar, I've sealed it tightly in a PRESERVE bottle mainly used for making jam, but it seem to be bubbling after a few days?what could be the problem

Comment: Did you process it in any way?  You say its in a "preserve bottle," but did you actually can it?  Or has it been stored in the refrigerator?  Either way, bubbling sounds like there's a lot of bacterial activity happening-- I'd toss it.

Comment: @rumtscho is correct if you did can it. Please describe the method you used if this is the case (hot water bath, time, etc.). If you didn't can it or store in the refrigerator, what you describe is pretty much inevitable.

Answer (score 3):

You are lucky - your sauce is spoiling and you are seeing it.

It is not safe to can random recipes, or to store them (uncanned) for more than 5 days in the refrigerator or more than 2 hours at room temperature. This means that, if you go ahead and can them neverthelss, you get one of the outcomes:

1. no pathogenic bacterial growth and no symptoms of spoilage.
2. no pathogenic bacterial growth, but symptoms of spoilage (caused by harmless bacteria or yeasts)
3. pathogenic bacterial growth and no symptoms of spoilage
4. pathogenic bacterial growth and symptoms of spolage.

Many people try it out, get outcome 1 (which is really frequent) and conclude that it is safe and outcomes 2, 3 or 4 will never happen. They are wrong.

What happened to you is either 2 or 4, because the bubbles are caused by bacteria digesting your sauce and creating gasses as a byproduct of their metabolism. There is no way to tell if the bacteria are harmless or pathogenic. So your food is spoiled.

The reason I said "lucky": You also narrowly missed case 3, which is the most dangerous. Then you would have been at real risk to get seriously ill, without any warning.